# Android Proximity sensor used for audio recording

Tags: android, audio, sensors, recording, proximity

The app requires the user to cover the proximity sensor to start audio recording,
and when the user uncovers the proximity sensor it should stop recording and open another activity that will later play the sound.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {



    if(event.values[0] == 0){
        proximity.setText(R.string.grav2);
        startRecording();
       /* if(event.values[0] == 0) {
            stopRecording();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, reprodutor.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }*/

    }
}
```

my issue is with this block of code, when i cover the sensor it starts and stops recording. please help!

Comment: I think the Proximity Sensor catches only the NewIntent (covering the sensor) and initiaited onSensorChanges to start recording, but because there's no logic with prox sensor done, it timeouts - that's why you lose the connection. My assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Im a beginner but with some though i managed to find a solution here it is for anyone who stumbles upon this same issue:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {



    if(event.values[0] == 0){
        proximity.setText(R.string.grav2);
        startRecording();
        flag = true;
       /* if(event.values[0] == 0) {
            stopRecording();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, reprodutor.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }*/

    }else{
        if(flag == true){
            stopRecording();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, reprodutor.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    }
}
```